# React app throwing error while i am importing docusign-esign module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docusignapi

create a react app

```
create-react-app demodocusign
```

Then install docusign-esign using npm.

```
npm install docusign-esign
```

Then import docusign in your app.js

```
const docusign = require("docusign-esign");
```

or

```
import docusign from "docusign-esign"
```

Then start the app

```
npm start
```

Then see the console or terminal ,its saying **Module not Found Can't resolve 'ApiClient'**

Note-Its working in Node express server but if i try to do the same thing in react ,it is throwing error

Comment: the name suggests that it is a node client. That means you need to use it only in nodejs environment. You can not run it in browser environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that this is client side code and our node.JS npm package can only be used from the server. You can only make the API calls from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have code like this in your .js code:

```
var docusign = require('docusign-esign');
docusign.ApiClinet // whatever you are doing with it.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but dude if i do not have the module,how can i access a key inside it(that's what your answer is suggesting),try to reproduce my steps i have written in the question

Comment: closing it as the docusign-esign package is not for frontend web,you can't use it directly

Comment: aha, this was client side code, I did not realize it. Then you are correct. Do you want me to post a reply to that effect just to make it clear to others reading this?

Comment: sure do man,post a reply confirming the issue and why it is not working